# How to send an url in an email in a wp8 app

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a way to send a http link in a wp8 app? I'm using

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
```

but whenever I include an http link in the body of my email, it just appears as regular text.

My http link is included in a default string, so it would kind of make sense, but I assumed that the email app receving the email would just detected the http://... and automatically converted it a link but that's not the case.

Should I include the http link within a specific tag??

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: try adding with A tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Would see link as normal Text in Body when Composing but in mail it would be seen highlighted as link

Try this :

```
    EmailComposeTask task = new EmailComposeTask();
    task.To = "Set Email here";
    task.Subject = "Subject goes here";
    task.Body = "Your Mesage goes here \n http://www.google.com";
    task.Show();
```

I have attached Screen Capture of inbox.

[image: Mail Message]

Comment: Hi, you're totally right. It is a bug in windows mail in windows 8 where it's not showing up as a link and I stupidly picked that one to test my email. The minute I used my work email or my personal email and checked it on my phone, the link was handled as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you called EmailComposeTask, It will show an `mail edit page`.

In this page, the http link can't be shown.

But when you send it, in the `Sent folder`, the mail can show http link.

And in the receiver's `Inbox`, it also can be shown.